# Error installing postgis with brew

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm having problems installing postgis using brew. I'm getting the following error(s):

```
==> Checking out http://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/trunk/
==> ./autogen.sh
==> ./configure --with-projdir=/usr/local --with-jsondir=/usr/local/opt/json-c --with-pgconfig=/usr/local/Cella
==> make
/bin/sh ../../libtool --mode=link clang -g -O2  -fno-common -DPIC  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -I../rt_core -I../../liblwgeom -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/1.11.1_3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.4.2/include   ../rt_core/librtcore.a raster2pgsql.o ../../liblwgeom/liblwgeom.la -L/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/1.11.1_3/lib -lgdal  -L/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.4.2/lib -lgeos_c  -liconv -lm -o raster2pgsql
libtool: link: cannot find the library `/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.la' or unhandled argument `/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.la'
make[2]: *** [raster2pgsql] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rtloader] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1

READ THIS: http://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
Postgis sql files not found (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/26604)
```

I have looked at the suggested issues with no luck. I have also tried to remove and reinstall postgres. Has anyone experienced similar issue and found a solution?

The /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.la is not ins this location. I have also tried reinstalling gdal and geos using brew.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Postgres.app comes with Postgis baked in. The Postgis folks even recommend it as the best way to get postgis on your mac. http://postgis.net/install/